# Is it possible to include a bibliography in a revealjs presentation using rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, reveal.js

I am trying to include a bibliography into a revealjs presentation using rmarkdown. However, despite the apparent inclusion of the bibliography in the pandoc processing (the pandoc command generated by rmarkdown includes the bib file and the citeproc filter), the generated html does not include the references. Using a different slide presentation generator and rmarkdown, such as ioslides, correctly includes the references. I was not able to find any obvious statement abuot supporting bibliography processing with rmarkdown and revealjs. Is it possible?

Comment: This works now out of the box, with up-to-date packages.

Comment: I had this issue with `pandoc 2.3.1` and resolved it by installing `2.7.2`.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround you can try the following:

1. create a separate Rmd-file and adapt the following:

   ```
   ---
   output: html_document
   bibliography: pathtomybibfile.bib
   nocite: | 
     @cite, @all, @your, @references
   ---
   ```
2. generate html-version of this file (e.g. name it bib.html)
3. include html within your revealjs-presentation via:

   ```
   # {data-background-iframe="bib.html"}
   ```